# Simple delete from database

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

I'm trying to delete from data from the database using a generic approach. it works for add, update but on delete I'm getting this:

> java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`mydb`.`testCases`, CONSTRAINT `fk03` FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES
>   `testType` (`idtestType`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Database

```
 //delete the object to the database
public static void deleteObject(Object object) {
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.GetSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(object);
        tx.commit();
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

My deletion attempt

```
  List<TestFlow> flow = getFlow(flowName);

   //delete the current one
    for(TestFlow tf : flow) {
        Database.deleteObject(tf);
    }
```

HBM

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestFlow" table="testFlow">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains the testCases flow details.
    </meta>
    <id name="id" type="int" column="idtestFlow">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
    <many-to-one name="testCase" class="com.atp.Model.TestCases.TestCase" column="testCase" fetch="select" cascade="all" lazy="false"/>
    <property name="rowNumber" column="rowNumber" type="int"/>
    <property name="testCaseStatus" column="testCaseStatus" type="int"/>
    <property name="params" column="params" type="string" />
    <property name="creationDate" column="creationDate" type="string"/>
    <property name="createdBy" column="createdBy" type="string"/>
    <property name="targetType" column="targetType" type="string"/>
    <property name="targetName" column="targetName" type="string"/>
    <property name="output" column="output" type="string"/>
    <property name="completionDate" column="completionDate" type="string"/>
    <property name="isCompleted" column="isCompleted" type="int"/>
</class>
```

Comment: This probably isn't really a Java question, just a MySQL one, and most likely the issue is that you are trying to delete a record which is still being referenced by records in other tables (that's basically what the error message is saying, in plain English).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your Foreign key in Appointments table has On delete: Restrict option. Change the Constraint appointments_user_id_foreign to On delete: Cascade and you should be able to delete Users while preserving Foreign key.

You can do it by 2 way:

a. Delete the associated records from the appointments table first with a separate delete statement.

b. **Add on delete cascade** option to appointments_user_id_foreign foreign key. This option will automatically remove any associated records from the appointments table for the user to be deleted when you delete the user's record.

**Try this as your need**

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from Stock where stockCode = :stockCode ");
q.setParameter("stockCode", "4715");
Stock stock = (Stock)q.list().get(0);
session.delete(stock);
```

**or**

```
  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE) 
    List<TestFlow> flow = getFlow(flowName);

   //delete the current one
    for(TestFlow tf : flow) {
        Database.deleteObject(tf);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete a parent record and allow the children records as ophans by default.

Add a delete cascade on the foreign key constraint to prevent the occurence of ophans.

```
ALTER TABLE mydb.testCases DROP FOREIGN KEY fk03;
ALTER TABLE mydb.testCases ADD CONSTRAINT fk03 FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES 
testType(idtestType) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

See [Hibernate – Cascade example (save, update, delete and delete-orphan)](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/) for more insight.